# Convert a message consumed by a KafkaListener in a json

Tags: java, json, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

In my spirng boot project, I have a model class (FunctionModel):

```
public class FunctionModel {

    protected Integer id;
    protected String name;

    @ApiModelProperty(value = "Identifier of function")
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @ApiModelProperty(value = "Name of function")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return ReflectionToStringBuilder.toString(this, ToStringStyle.SHORT_PREFIX_STYLE);
    }

}
```

I send a message with Kafka and this message is consumed by a KafkaListener in this way:

```
@KafkaListener(topics = ConstantTopics.TOPIC_FUNCTION, containerFactory = "kafkaListenerContainerFactoryString")
public void consumerJsonFunction(Object o) throws Exception {
    logger.info("Consumed message: " + o);
    System.out.println("Consume message:" + o.toString());
}
```

So, in Console i see this logs:

```
[2m2021-02-02 17:13:21.950[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m18680[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[ntainer#5-0-C-1][0;39m [36mc.n.g.s.service.SupervisorService       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Consumed message: ConsumerRecord(topic = function, partition = 0, offset = 21, CreateTime = 1612282401918, serialized key size = -1, serialized value size = 175, headers = RecordHeaders(headers = [RecordHeader(key = __TypeId__, value = [99, 111, 109, 46, 110, 116, 116, 100, 97, 116, 97, 46, 105, 111, 116, 46, 101, 108, 100, 46, 97, 112, 105, 46, 109, 111, 100, 101, 108, 115, 46, 70, 117, 110, 99, 116, 105, 111, 110, 77, 111, 100, 101, 108])], isReadOnly = false), key = null, value = {"name":"esponenziale","language":"java","code":"codec","registryImageUrl":"abc123","registryUser":null,"registryToken":null,"description":null,"id":3,"requirements":"def456"})
Consume message:ConsumerRecord(topic = function, partition = 0, offset = 21, CreateTime = 1612282401918, serialized key size = -1, serialized value size = 175, headers = RecordHeaders(headers = [RecordHeader(key = __TypeId__, value = [99, 111, 109, 46, 110, 116, 116, 100, 97, 116, 97, 46, 105, 111, 116, 46, 101, 108, 100, 46, 97, 112, 105, 46, 109, 111, 100, 101, 108, 115, 46, 70, 117, 110, 99, 116, 105, 111, 110, 77, 111, 100, 101, 108])], isReadOnly = false), key = null, value = {"name":"esponenziale","language":"java","code":"codec","registryImageUrl":"abc123","registryUser":null,"registryToken":null,"description":null,"id":3,"requirements":"def456"})
```

How can I go about transforming the consumed message into a json containing the model information of the original class?

Comment: 1) What value deserializer are you using? 2) What happens when you use `consumerJsonFunction(FunctionModel o)`? 3) Did you read the spring-kafka documentation around the JSON serialization section?

Answer (score 0):

You can directly accept the payload in **FunctionModel** instead of accepting it as an Object. You can use something like this:

```html
@KafkaListener(topics = ConstantTopics.TOPIC_FUNCTION, containerFactory = "kafkaListenerContainerFactoryString")
public void consumerJsonFunction(@Payload FunctionModel o) throws Exception {
    //Do something
}
```